# How to change the icon of a shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, icons

I've seen tutorials stating that to change the icon you right click shortcut-> left click properties, and then click "change icon" and pick an icon to use for your shortcut. I've followed the exact same process, creating a .ico file that is a 128x128 pixels wide in the same directory as the shortcut leads to but my computer refuses to pick it up. 
How can I change the icon of a shortcut in Windows 10?

Comment: If your *.ico file has an appropriate format it works. I've created a JPG with Paint and changed the format to ICO with IrfanView - no problem!

Comment: @duDE I downloaded a .png image off the internet and changed its size to 128x128 using paint.net. Then I replaced it's extension from .png to .ico and put it next to my .exe that the shortcut points to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest using online png to ico conversion instead of just changing file extension.

Comment: You have only changed the extension - that's what was wrong :) You need to CONVERT the file to ICO!

Comment: @duDE I'm studying computer security so I really should have known this. -1 to me :(

Comment: No problem, try with converted ICO file, it shall work :) All the best!

Comment: @duDE it worked! feel free to make an answer and I'll accept. You deserve it!